# saber el numero de divs que esta fuera de otro

Tags: jquery, css

me gustaría saber ¿Como se puede obtener la cantidad de divs, en este caso de la clase div_principal, que no están incluido del div de clase div_global?. En este caso debería retornar valor.

```
<div class="div_global">
    <div class="div_principal"></div>
    <div class="div_principal"></div>
    <div class="div_principal"></div>
</div>

<div class="div_principal"></div>
<div class="div_principal"></div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Puedes utilizar [`.not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not/) para eliminar los `<div>` que están dentro.

```js
var divsFuera = $(".div_principal").not(".div_global .div_principal").length;
console.log(divsFuera);
```

```css
.div_global {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.div_principal {
  height: 10px;
  background: red;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div_global">
    <div class="div_principal"></div>
    <div class="div_principal"></div>
    <div class="div_principal"></div>
</div>

<div class="div_principal"></div>
<div class="div_principal"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Cuenta la cantidad total de elementos `<div>` dentro de `<div class="div_global">`
2. Cuenta la cantidad de `<div class="div_principal">` que tengas y a ellas le sumas sus elementos `<div>` hijos.
3. Obtén la diferencia.

```
    var divG = $('.div_global div').length;
    var divP = $('.div_principal, .div_principal div').length;
    var dife = divG - divP;
```

La variable `dife` tiene lo que necesitas.

Answer (score 1):

Una versión más sencilla. En este caso buscamos los `.div_principal` **desciendentes directos** de `body` con el operador de selección `>`:

```js
var divsFuera = $('body > .div_principal').css('background', '#00BBFF');

$('#fuera').text($('#fuera').text() + divsFuera.length)
```

```css
.div_global {
  background: #F7F7F7;
  padding : 5px;
}

.div_principal {
  height: 10px;
  background: #FFBB00;
  padding: 10px;
  margin : 5px;
  border-radius : 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  
<div class="div_global">
  <div class="div_principal"></div>
  <div class="div_principal"></div>
  <div class="div_principal"></div>
</div>

<div class="div_principal"></div>
<div class="div_principal"></div>

<div id="fuera"> Divs fuera : </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar este código

```
$(function() {
   var divs=0;
   $(".div_principal").each(function(){
          if(!$(this).parents("div").hasClass('div_global')){
                divs++;
          }
   });
   alert(divs);
});
```

puedes probarlo en [este fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rsse5xhe/)

Comment: Como consejo, `alert` no es un metodo de debug valido porque puede originar problemas como bloqueo del browser, es mejor usar `console.log` para mas info mirar [aqui](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8825384/alert-is-bad-really)